# Weird value obtained when outputting

Tags: c++

I have this simple program that basically accepts user input and outputs it to the screen. This program works fine when I input an integer. However, when I input a string literal, this negative integer is obtained as the output. (-858993460), regardless of any string input size.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, if that matters.

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
   int a;
   std::string b;
   b = "Type something";
   std::cout << b << std::endl;
   std::cin >> a;
   std::cout << "You said " << a << std::endl;
}
```

I have tried searching but to no avail. Hence, I have two questions.

1) Why is it outputting this particular negative integer when I gave it a string input?

2) Why didn't the program give me a compilation error, syntax error, or a crash? Instead, why did it go on outputting that integer?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How do you expect a string to be put into an integer?

Comment: Yeah, but why did it output that certain integer? Why didn't it give me an error? That's my question.

Comment: Letters have integer representations

Comment: try to run it again after properly initializing `a` to lets say `int a = 0;`

Comment: Bad input does not give you an error.  `cin` gives you ways to find out if it is `good()` or not and if it is not you can clean it up and try again/

Comment: @tobi303 Yeap, it does output a value of 0 to the console.

Comment: my point was just to make you notice that the strange number you get printed has nothing to do with what the user enters. The value of `a` isnt modified by `cin >> a` because the operation fails

Comment: It is not possible to "input" a string literal. A string literal is a source code construct.

Comment: What was the exact input you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why is it outputting this particular negative integer when I gave it a string input?

Because your integer was not initialized to anything, it's outputting whatever is there (primitives like `int` do not get default values when declared at function-level scope). Reading of the integer from the stream failed because you provided a string literal, so the integer value was not changed. If you initialize the value of the integer to `42` you'll see that it's value was unchanged when it gets printed ([until C++11. After C++11 the value will become 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)).

> 2) Why didn't the program give me a compilation error, syntax error, or a crash? Instead, why did it go on outputting that integer?

streams force the programmer to check what happened (in general*). They have implicit conversions to booleans so you can conveniently check if anything went wrong.

Try to augment your code like so:

```
std::cin >> a;
if (!std::cin)
{
   std::cerr << "Failed to read!" << std::endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

[Demo1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9jp9rGu5lu0fLy1T)

*If you want `std::cin` to throw an exception on failure, then you can use [`basic_ios::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) to do so:

```
std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::badbit | std::istream::failbit);
```

[Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vP9hj6P4tg3pX3EX)

Answer (score 1):

There is already an excellent answer. I just want to add for the second question

> 2) Why didn't the program give me a compilation error, syntax error,
>   or a crash? Instead, why did it go on outputting that integer?

error?

The compiler cannot know what the user will write. It could it could be something that can be streamed to an `int` but it also could be that it cannot. Thus the compiler has no chance to issue a warning/error in this situation.

crash?

If this code would cause a crash then it would be impossible to use `cin` to write code that cannot be crashed by malformed user input. That would make `cin` rather useless.

conclusion?

It is your responsibility to check if the input operation went ok and to react accordingly if it didnt.

Answer (score -3):

You're storing user input in an int. 
I suggest you convert the input string to int as in 
std::cin >> atoi(a);

Comment: did you ever use this and it compiled?

Comment: `std::cin >> a` *does* read an integer (if that's what is entered) and stores it into `a`. `std::cin >> atoi( a )` won't even compile as you're trying to pass an uninitialized integer (`a`) to a function expecting a `char const *` parameter (`atoi()`), and then do unspeakable things to that function's return value...